# Change clicked value without using index?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to change value from false to true after click. I found example that do same by index number, but is it's possible to do without index? Just by name?

```
 data() {
    return  {
        names: [
         {n: 'Dima', isClck: false},
         {n: 'Roma', isClck: false},
         {n: 'Masha', isClck: false},
        ],

    }
 },
 methods :
 {
    MyClick(name)
    {
     // come code here
    }
```

Comment: `this.names.find(obj => obj.n === name).isClck = true`

Comment: What does your template look like?

Answer (score 0):

````
```
MyClick(name)
    {
     let selected = this.names.filter(i => i.n === name)[0]
             //or = this.names.find(i => i.n === name)
    this.isClck = !this.isClck
    }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this purely in your template

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="name in names">
    <button @click="name.isClick = !name.isClick">{{name.n}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```